# Is there a known solution to $f(x) = (1-x)f(x^2)$?

Tags: special-functions

The functional equation $f(x) = (1-x)f(x^2)$ (with $f(0)=1$) has a simple solution that can be expressed as a rapidly converging infinite product
$$f(x) = \prod_{n=0}^\infty (1 - x^{2^n}) = (1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^4)(1-x^8)\cdots$$
and as a more slowly converging power series
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{H(n)}x^n = 1 - x - x^2 + x^3 -\cdots,$$
where $H(n)$ is the *Hamming weight* of $n$ (i.e., the number of 1's in the binary representation of $n$).

Is anything known about this function $f$?  Does it have a simple description in terms of more familiar functions?

Comment: This function has a natural boundary on the unit circle.  What "familiar function" has that?

Comment: For $x=1/2$ this gives the "Thue-Morse"-constant (or something rational tightly related) . There is a bit of discussion about it online available.

Comment: I think $1/f(x)$ gives the generating function for binary partitions. See, e.g., http://theory.cs.uvic.ca/inf/nump/BinaryPartition.html

Answer (score 3):

*(I made this comment an answer so that the question can be "completed" by "accepting" this answer)*

There is an interesting discussion around the Thue-Morse-sequence/constant in the following two articles of J. Shallit/JP Allouche, where the function in question occurs in a wider context.
See links at Jeffrey Shallit's homepage:

- The [ubiquituous Thue-Morse-Sequence](http://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/ubiq.ps)  *(this is a postscript file
  and can be converted (for instance by Ghostscript) to pdf to be readable.)* In the paper your
  formula occurs in proposition 2.
- A powerpoint-like overview is in this [pdf-file](http://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Talks/green3.pdf) (somehow a summary, possibly an extension) of the first paper. Again you find your function discussed (in short)
  and referenced from a wider context (see page 36 "Another definition").

*[update] I included the hint to Ghostscript due to the comments to this answer*

Comment: [A non-mathematical comment] "this is a postscript file and should be converted to pdf to be readable": This is not true! You can use for instance Ghostscript (free software, available at least for Linux and Windows and I imagine for a number of other platforms too: http://www.ghostscript.com/) to read the Postscript file.

Comment: :-) Yes, I'm so used to the ps to pdf-conversion by ghostscript *in the background* that I even forget to mention it...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, whether the following counts as "is anything known", but I found it interesting.
Consider the separation according to the Hamming weight:
$$ \begin{array}{} 
 a_0(x) &= 1 &\\
 a_1(x) &=   & x^1+x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + ... \\
 a_2(x) &=   & x^3+x^5 + x^6 + x^9 + ... \\
 a_3(x) &=   & x^7+x^{11} + x^{13} + x^{14} + ... \\
 ... & = ...
\end{array}$$ which are all convergent for $|x| \lt 1$, then
$$ s_0(x) = a_0(x) +a_1(x)+a_2(x)+ ... \\ 
    = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(x) \\ 
    = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k \\ 
    =  { 1 \over 1-x } \tag2$$
and
$$ s_1(x) = a_0(x) -a_1(x)+a_2(x)- ... \\
       = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k a_k(x) \\
       = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{H(k)} x^k \\
      = f(x) \tag3$$
I found it then interesting, that at $x=1/2$ the evaluation $a_1(1/2)$ is known to be a transcendental number. But what about the other $a_k(1/2)$ ? If I recall it correctly they are all transcendental numbers, but don't have it at hand how this has been shown; I think they might be rational multiples of each other): just (another) infinite set of transcendental numbers adding up to a rational one.

---

***[update]*** If I recall correctly the $a_k(1/2)$ can be generated as rational compositions of $a_1(1/2),a_1(1/2^2),a_1(1/2^3),...$ (or very similar) applying the Newton-method of converting a sequence of powersums into symmetric polynomials. For instance,
$$a_1(1/2) \approx 0.816421509022 \\
a_2(1/2) \approx 0.175061285686 \\$$
and also
$$ [(a_1(1/2)^2-(a_1(1/2) -1/2) )/2,a_2(1/2)] \\ 
 [0.175061285686, 0.175061285686]
$$
using Pari/GP, reflecting the second power  $(x^1 + x^2 + x^4+x^8+...)^2= 2(x^3 + x^5+x^6 + ...) + (x^2+x^4+x^8+...) \\ = 2 a_2(x)+ a_1(x^2) =  2 a_2(x)+ (a_1(x)-x) $

Comment: This follows from some results about numbers whose binary (actually arbitrary-base, but binary is the relevant case here) representations form _automatic sequences_ ; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_sequence#Automatic_real_number for more pointers.  (The automata for recognizing each individual sequence is fairly trivial, just a 'count-to-$k$' FSM.  There's no _uniform_ automaton that covers all the sequences, but that's irrelevant here.)

Comment: Incidentally, Alpha gives $\frac{a_1(1/2)}{a_2(1/2)}$ as approximately $4.663632$, and passing that into the ISC doesn't yield anything particularly interesting.  I imagine it's probably transcendental as well. Perhaps if the ratio of two automatic reals is also automatic...

Comment: @Steven: in fact there should be a rational composition in terms of powers of $a_1(x)$ and thus all $a_k(1/2)$ should come out to be transcendental ; I've put that idea into my answer.

Comment: @Steven: the ratio gives $ \displaystyle 4.663632...= {a_1 \over a_2 } = { 2 \over a_1 -1 + {1 \over 2 a_1}}$ as a rational composition of $a_1$ and $a_1^2$